# Cucumber specific scenario to run conditionally

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, scenarios

I have multiple features in my project which each contain multiple scenarios.

I want to know if I can skip one or more of the features or scenarios from running *(while the rest still run)* based on a specific value set in my application.yaml. *(or if there's any better way of doing it)*

I thought I can add an And statement after the Given and check the property but I don't know how to skip the scenario within its implementation.

example:

I have a property called "type" which can be "apple" or "orange" and I have a feature with the following scenarios:

- scenario A: to only run when type is apple
- scenario B: to only run when type is orange
- scenario C: will run regardless of the type

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [Tag expressions](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions) to tag your features / scenarios. In your example: `@apple`, `@orange`
2. You can use these tags to specify which features / scenarios you want to run. How to do so, depends on how you are running your tests, but you'll need to provide `tags=@apple` or `tags=@orange` depending on which you want to run, or omit tags if you want to run all of them.

Comment: Thanks Marit, so basically I just create a tag and annotate my scenario with it and in my cucumber options I pass it as tags like "not @apple" (assuming I don't want apple to run) ?

Comment: Yes, or alternatively pass tags "@apple" if you do want everything tagged `@apple` to run.